# Can't use method UpdateRowCellsBuilder from smartsheets

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v1

I'm trying to update a cell in smartsheets but it is returning the error -

```
Error   1   The type name 'UpdateRowCellsBuilder' does not exist in the type 'Tannery_Data.Cell'
```

The namespace is called Tannery_Data?

I am using these references:

```
using Smartsheet.Api;
using Smartsheet.Api.Models;
using Smartsheet.Api.OAuth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

And here is the code

```
namespace Tannery_Data
{
    class smartsheetQuery
    {
        public Token token;                                          
        String API = "XXXXXXX";                  
        SmartsheetClient smartsheet; 
        long sheetID;
        long workspaceID;

        public smartsheetQuery()
        {
            token = new Token();
            token.AccessToken = API;
            smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token.AccessToken).Build();  /
            sheetID = 1378721379706756;
            workspaceID = 4196096982443908;
        }

        public void updateCell()
        {
            IList<Cell> cells = new Cell.UpdateRowCellsBuilder().AddCell(7735727405459332L, "TESTING").Build();
            smartsheet.Rows().UpdateCells(7602661257176964L, cells);
        }
```

Absolutely no idea what is going on here?

Comment: Do you have a class named "Cell" in your Tannery_Data namespace? You could try to provide the fully qualified name to the Cell class by using `new Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell.UpdateRowCellsBuilder().AddCell(7735727405459332L, "TESTING").Build()`

Comment: Hey Brett, that worked thanks! Just wondering how does the program know what sheet I am on? Or can it find the sheet via the columnID's etc?

Comment: Also, did you want to answer this? If it is quite specific happy to remove post.

Comment: You are correct the sheet id is not required to update cells. The C# sdk is using the [REST API](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation) for all requests that are sent to Smartsheet. For updating cells it specifically uses the [Update Row Cells](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.iivq0zgz3g8q) request which only needs the row id and the column id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is stating that it is looking for a Cell class inside the Tannery_Data namespace. There are two ways to resolve this.

1. Rename the Cell class to something different.

or

2. Use the fully qualified name when referencing a class in another namespace. For example instead of using `new Cell.UpdateRowCellsBuilder()` use `new Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell.UpdateRowCellsBuilder()`